# Remove white space under sticky footer in Bootstrap 4 on iPhone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I get this white space below my sticky footer, when in small mobile devices. For an example when viewing in 'iPhone SE' screen size.

I used this same footer and css from bootstrap examples but unable to make the whitespace go away.

I thought this happens because my text is long, then I added footer height using media queries, but it doesn't look good. I do not know how to fix it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;

}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #0000ff
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}


.text-muted {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0057)https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer/ -->
<html lang="en" class="gr__getbootstrap_com"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Sticky Footer Template for Bootstrap</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

  <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">This is a test to check this sticky footer. This footer breaks in small screens.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens because on small screens the footer breaks into two lines, and since you have set `line-height:60px` it results in a total of `120px`, which overcome the `60px` height set.

You can either handle it with [media queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/), or by setting `overflow:hidden;` (not really the best solution), or by replacing the `line-height` with some `padding`.

Here is an example with media queries. (with your text, the problem appears around 514px)

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;

}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0000ff
}

@media all  and (min-width: 514px){
    .footer {
        /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
    }
}

@media all  and (max-width: 514px){
    .footer {
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}


.text-muted {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0057)https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer/ -->
<html lang="en" class="gr__getbootstrap_com"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Sticky Footer Template for Bootstrap</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

  <body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">

    <!-- Begin page content -->
    

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">This is a test to check this sticky footer. This footer breaks in small screens.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  

</body></html>
```

Comment: This almost solved it. Really appreciate your help. Cheers.